# Tkinter gui doesn't work Mouse and keyboard modules

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, mouse

I was trying to make an auto clicker using Mouse and keyboard modules and tkinter as the gui and wrote this code

```
#Import
import tkinter as tk
import random as r8
import keyboard as kb
import mouse as ms

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.joesd()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.joe = tk.Frame(self)#main frame
        self.joe.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.joe, text='Example text', height=5, width=30)
        self.lbl.pack(side="top")# where the label will be located
        self.lb = tk.Label(self.joe, text='Example Text', height=5, width=35)
        self.lb.pack(side="top")# where the label will be located
    def joesd(self):
        while True:
            if kb.is_pressed('q') == True:
                ms.press('left')
                ms.release('left')

root = tk.Tk() 
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Then I noticed that the gui never appears but will appear if I removed

```
    def joesd(self):
        while True:
            if kb.is_pressed('q') == True:
                ms.press('left')
                ms.release('left')
```

What should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `keyboard`/`mouse` module when using `tkinter`. Instead look at `tkinter` event bindings.

Comment: `while` will stop `mainloop` from updating the GUI.

Comment: @TheLizzard can tkinter event bindings automate key pressing?

Comment: @CoolCloud I removed while but still nothing happend

Comment: @AmirTheDev I suggest that you look at a tkinter tutorial. To use tkinter's event bindings you pass in a function that tkinter calls when somethings happens like a mouse press/keyboard button is pressed.

Comment: @TheLizzard I am asking whether tkinter can simulate key press.

Comment: @AmirTheDev No but why do you need that?

Comment: @TheLizzard to make an auto clicker

Comment: You could try to alter `after()` to emulate a while loop, don't know if it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why GUI does not show up is that before the code hits `mainloop()` it goes into a infinite loop(`while` loop) and it cannot reach `mainloop` and hence window does not show up and events are not processed. So what you should do is get rid of `while`. One way is to use `after()` method to emulate `while`.

```
def joesd(self):
    if kb.is_pressed('q'):
        ms.press('left')
        ms.release('left')
        
    self.after(100,self.joesd)
```

This will repeat the function every 100 ms, you can reduce it to 1ms too. But make sure it is not too much for the system to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use while loop in a tkinter application.  You can register a callback using `kb.on_press_key()` instead:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        ...
        #self.joesd() # <- not necessary
        kb.on_press_key("q", self.on_key_press)

    ...

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        #print("q pressed", event)
        ms.press('left')
        ms.release('left')
        # above two lines can be replaced by ms.click('left')
```

Comment: Although this does work it's not what I need, I need the button to continuously be clicked d @CoolCloud did give me another successful answer, but thank you for taking time to review my code.

Comment: @AmirTheDev If you keep the "q" key pressed, the callback will be kept executing.

Comment: That could work but it still not what I need, I want to make an auto-clicker that doesn't require a person pressing something.

Comment: @AmirTheDev Then I wonder why your code keeps checking `kb.is_pressed("q")`?